# Upload multiple APKs to Play Store and localize them in different languages

Tags: android, localization, apk

Is it possible to upload multiple APKs for the same app on the Google play store and localize them in different languages? So that if an English user downloads the app, he will download the APK compiled in English. Or if an Italian user downloads the app, he will download the APK compiled in Italian. And so on. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**

Multiple APK feature doesn't support filtering by country and it only supports for following filters

- Support different OpenGL texture compression formats with each APK.
- Support different screen sizes and densities with each APK. Support
- different device feature sets with each APK. Support different
- platform versions with each APK. Support different CPU architectures with each APK (such as for ARM, x86, and MIPS, when your app uses the
  Android NDK).

for more information please refer here [developer.android.com / Supported Filters](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters)

---

> **Suggestion for your problem**

You can **localize** your app with Resources. Resources in the sense text strings, layouts, sounds, graphics, and any other static data that can be translated to another language.

Suppose that your application's default language is English. Suppose also that you want to localize all the text in your application to French, and most of the text in your application (everything except the application's title) to Japanese. In this case, you could create three alternative strings.xml files, each stored in a locale-specific resource directory:

- **`res/values/strings.xml`**
  Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses, including text for a string named title.
- **`res/values-fr/strings.xml`**
  Contain French text for all the strings, including title.
- **`res/values-ja/strings.xml`**
  Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.

There is a perfect guide for localization in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Please have a read